# Searching a has_many through table from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, form-for

I am at a loss.  I have a form_for that is working fine to create a new record in a has_many through relationship.  What I'm trying to do is to find out whether the join table has a particular value in it and save differently depending on the results.

So, using the example from the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), I have:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments, :patients
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments, :physicians
end
```

I've got a working form_form using `<%= form_for(@physician) do |f| %>`
Inside the form I have included this line to pass a non-model variable to the physician controller that specifies a particular patient: `<%= hidden_field_tag :patient_id, :value => @patient_id%>`.  I've checked all the values and they pass into the controller's create action just fine.  Here's where my problem arises:

Assume I'm trying to assign a second physician to an existing appointment.

From inside the physician controller's create action I am trying to search the appointment table for the :patient_id that is passed in using the hidden field.  I want to save the results differently depending on whether or not there is an existing appointment for that patient.  IF I cannot find the patient_id I want to create both patient and appointment for that physician.  IF I find that the patient in the appointment table, I want to create a record that associates the physician with the patient through the appointment table.

I hope this is somewhat clear?

Comment: What do you mean by `IF I cannot find the patient_id I want to create both patient and appointment for that physician.`

Comment: Sorry.  Inside the Physician controller's create method, I want to search the appointments and see if the particular patient_id exists.  If I cannot find the patient_id, create the patient and the appointment, IF i can find the patient_id associate the physician with the patient in the appointment table.

Comment: If you are searching the Appointments table for patient id and not finding the patient id, that means the patient doesn't have an appointment. It does not mean that the patient does not exist. The patient record will be in the Patient table. The Appointment table simply contains a foreign key pointing to it.